# TestCase mouseDrag only clicks item inside Flickable but does not drag

Tags: qt, qml, mouseevent, qt5.5

In a QML TestCase, I'm trying to setup automatic scrolling of a ListView that is contained inside a Flickable (to add a custom footer that can be flicked into view, which wouldn't happen with just `ListView { footer: Component {} }`)

However, the `mouseDrag` only seems to click the correct coordinate, but not drag it to any direction. Here is a simplified version that is as close to the real one as possible:

**Implementation.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5

FocusScope {
    width: 1920
    height: 1080

    Flickable {
        objectName: 'flickableList'
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        clip: true
        width: parent.width
        height: 240
        contentHeight: 500

        ListView {
            interactive: false
            height: parent.height
            width: parent.width

            model: ['example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4', 'example5']
            delegate: Item {
                width: 300
                height: 100
                Text {
                    text: modelData
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: footer
        height: 100
        width: parent.width
    }
}
```

**TheTest.qml**

```
// The relevant part
var theList = findChild(getView(), 'flickableList')
var startY = 220
var endY = 20
mouseDrag(theList, 100, startY, 100, endY, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier, 100)
```

So, when I'm viewing the UI testrunner, I can see it clearly click on the correct delegate (it has a focus highlight in the actual implementation), ie. the third item "example3", which starts at Y 200 and ends at Y 300). But the drag event never happens. Nothing moves on the screen, and `compare(theList.contentY, 200)` says it is still at position `0`. I would expect it to be at `200`, since the mouse is supposed to be `mouseDrag`ging from position `220` to `20`, ie. scrolling the list down by `200`. And `220` is also within the visible height (`240`).

Just to be sure, I also reversed the Y values, but also no movement:

```
var theList = findChild(getView(), 'flickableList')
var startY = 20
var endY = 220
mouseDrag(theList, 100, startY, 100, endY, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier, 100)
```

Also, as the 3rd item clearly is clicked on (it gets highlighted), the passed item `theList` (= the Flickable), should be valid.

Edit:
Oh, and this does scroll the list, but it goes all the way to the bottom of the list (388 px down in the actual implementation, even when the delta is just 30 pixels):

```
mousePress(theList, startX, startY)
mouseMove(theList, endX, endY)
mouseRelease(theList, endX, endY)
```

**So the question is:**

Does `mouseDrag` only work for specific types of components (ie. does not work on `Flickable`?), or is there something missing? How can I get it to scroll the list down? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your tag says you're using Qt 5.5 - I would recommend trying Qt 5.14 if possible, as there was a fix that might help:

> mouseDrag(): ensure that intermediate moves are done for all drags
>
> [...]
>
> In practice, this means that mouseDrag() never did intermediate moves
>   (i.e. what happens during a drag in real life) for drags that go from
>   right to left or upwards.

https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtdeclarative/+/281903

If that doesn't help, or upgrading is not an option, I would recommend looking at Qt's own tests (although they are written in C++):

https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/tests/auto/quick/qquickflickable/tst_qquickflickable.cpp#n1150

Comment: Would be nice, but unfortunately we are forced to use 5.5 :)

Answer (score 0):

I think mouseDrag only works for mouse area. You could wrap every object with that.
But in the end, you need to use a mouse area inside you delegate and Drag and Drop it.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-drag.html

```
import QtQuick 2.5

FocusScope {
    width: 1920
    height: 1080

    Flickable {
        objectName: 'flickableList'
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        clip: true
        width: parent.width
        height: 240
        contentHeight: 500

        ListView {
            interactive: false
            height: parent.height
            width: parent.width

            model: ['example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4', 'example5']
            delegate: DelegateList{
                textAreaText = modelData
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: footer
        height: 100
        width: parent.width
    }
}
```

And the DelegateList.qml

```
Item {
    id: root

    property alias textAreaText: textArea.text

    width: 300
    height: 100
    Text {
        id: textArea
    }

    Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active
    Drag.hotSpot.x: 10
    Drag.hotSpot.y: 10

    MouseArea {
        id: dragArea
        anchors.fill: parent

        drag.target: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this out, but this one seems to drag the delegate to a new position (eg. move item3 to the position where item1 was), instead of scrolling the Flickable up/down, which is what I want to do.

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't get it right. In that case, could be that you used some coordinates, unprecise. I suggest two things:
1. anchor the flikable scope to the top parent
2. use the functions object mapFromItem(item, real x, real y, real width, real height) in order to be sure the coordinates are right
 https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html